# Reload certs without restart of server kestrel

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ssl-certificate, kestrel-http-server, kestrel

I use Let's Encrypt certificates that are renewed every 90 days and I would like to know if there is a way to reload certificates without restarting the kestrel server.

I tried this answer on github but I just don't get it, or I can't get it to work:
https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/2967

Right now I have this code:

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseKestrel(options =>
                    {
                        options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 80);
                        options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 443, listenOptions =>
                        {
                            listenOptions.UseHttps(httpsOptions =>
                            {
                                httpsOptions.ServerCertificateSelector = (context, dnsName) =>
                                {
                                    var certificate = new X509Certificate2("C:\\Users\\jserra\\Desktop\\folder1\\Cert1.pfx", "`P@ssw0rd");
                                    return certificate;
                                };
                            });
                        });
                    }).UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

This code makes a new var certificate for every request.
So I have 2 certs, Cert1.pfx and Cert2.pfx.
First I try to make a request, it loads the Cert1 and then at runtime with file explorer I rename Cert1.pfx to Cert1.pfx.old.
Then I rename Cert2.pfx to Cert1.pfx, I make a new request and the server this time is using the new certificate.

Does this make sense? It is good to make a new var certificate = Cert1.pfx every new request?

If you have something in mind to solve my question I would like to read it, thanks all.

Comment: Doesn't really solve your problem, but some food for thought: If your certificate needs to change, you're probably overdue for rebooting for security updates.

Comment: So what's the solution?

Comment: Oh you answered it yourself, the comment in the linked issue mentions you're responsible for caching the certificate to avoid loading it on every new request.

Answer (score 1):

Put the certificate in a static variable. Store a second DateTime in another static variable. When the date time variable is older than a threshold, reload the certificate from file.

```cs
public static class CertificateCache
{
    private const string certificatePath = "C:\\Users\\jserra\\Desktop\\folder1\\Cert1.pfx";

    // password should be loaded from environment variable or configuration
    private const string password = "`P@ssw0rd";

    // cache certificate for one day
    private static readonly TimeSpan cacheTime = TimeSpan.FromDays(1.0);
    private static readonly object certificateLock = new();

    private static X509Certificate2 certificate;
    private static DateTime lastCertificateLoad;

    public static X509Certificate2 GetCertificate()
    {
        if (DateTime.UtcNow - lastCertificateLoad > cacheTime)
        {
            lock (certificateLock)
            {
                // in case multiple callers got through the first if statement, check again
                if (DateTime.UtcNow - lastCertificateLoad > cacheTime)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var oldCertificate = certificate;
                        certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificatePath, password);
                        lastCertificateLoad = DateTime.UtcNow;
                        // dispose of old certificate after 1 minute to eliminate memory leaks, this allows any connections using it to finish up cleanly
                        if (oldCertificate is not null)
                        {
                            Task.Run(async () =>
                            {
                                await Task.Delay(60000);
                                oldCertificate.Dispose();
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        // manual intervention probably required, send an email or high priority notification
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return certificate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution uses IMemoryCache from ASP.NET and PEM certificates.

Main logic is encapsulated in `HttpsConfigurationService`:

```
public class HttpsConfigurationService : IHttpsConfigurationService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HttpsConfigurationService> _logger;
        private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;
        private readonly CertificateOptions _certificateOptions;

        private const string CertificateKey = "HttpsCertificate";

        public HttpsConfigurationService(ILogger<HttpsConfigurationService> logger,
            IMemoryCache memoryCache, IOptions<CertificateOptions> certificateOptions)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _memoryCache = memoryCache;
            _certificateOptions = certificateOptions.Value;
        }


        public void ConfigureKestrel(KestrelServerOptions serverOptions)
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(_certificateOptions?.Path))
            {
                _logger.LogError("Certificate Path is missing");
                return;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_certificateOptions?.KeyPath))
            {
                _logger.LogError("Certificate KeyPath is missing");
                return;
            }

            serverOptions.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 443, listenOptions =>
            {
                listenOptions.UseHttps(httpsOptions =>
                {
                    httpsOptions.ServerCertificateSelector = (context, dnsName) =>
                    {
                        var certificate = _memoryCache.GetOrCreate(
                            CertificateKey,
                            cacheEntry =>
                            {
                                cacheEntry.AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);

                                var newCertificate = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile(_certificateOptions.Path, _certificateOptions.KeyPath);
                                _logger.LogInformation("Certificate was loaded from the disk");
                                
                                return newCertificate;
                            });

                        return certificate;
                    };
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

In `Program.cs` you can use this service:

```
builder.ConfigureWebHost((b) =>
            {
                b.ConfigureKestrel((context, serverOptions) =>
                {
                    var httpsConfigurationService = serverOptions.ApplicationServices.GetService<IHttpsConfigurationService>();
                    httpsConfigurationService.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions);
                });
            });
```

Do not forget to register the service in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddTransient<IHttpsConfigurationService, HttpsConfigurationService>();
```

For configuration I've create a class `CertificateOptions`:

```
public class CertificateOptions
    {
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public string KeyPath { get; set; }
    }
```

And registered it in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.Configure<CertificateOptions>(config.GetSection("Kestrel:Certificates:Default"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to modify @Ihor Romanchuk answer slightly to get it to work

```
var newCertificate = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile(_certificateOptions.Path, _certificateOptions.KeyPath);
_logger.LogInformation("Certificate was loaded from the disk");
   
 return new X509Certificate2(newCertificate.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12));
 //return newCertificate;
```

The original solution works but only in Linux. You will come across an error with windows `Failed to authenticate HTTPS connection. System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090327): An unknown error occurred while processing the certificate.` .

You can find details on the errors here (which is also where I got the solution from): https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/45680